# Defining parameters in SQLDatasource in devexpress

Tags: devexpress, sqldatasource

I have a SQLDataSource that has an insert statement and parameters defined, please see photo below:

[image]

As I run my program, it will always states that it cannot find the txtlName control. What is wrong with my implementation? Can someone tell how to fix this?

This is my mark up code for my sqldatasource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDRFConnectionString %>" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO MDRF_Main(MDRF_LName, MDRF_FName, MDRF_MName, MDRF_Department, MDRF_RequestType, MDRF_Status, MDRF_WorkflowId, MDRF_Company, MDRF_Remarks, MDRF_RequestModule, MDRF_DateRequired, MDRF_Priority, MDRF_ResponseTime, MDRF_Module, MDRF_DocNum) VALUES (@lname, @fname, @mname, @dept, @rt, @status, @work, @comp, @remarks, @rm, CONVERT(datetime, @date) , @prio, @response, @module, @dn)" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource4_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MDRF_Main]">
                 <InsertParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLname" Name="lname" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFname" Name="fname" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtMname" Name="mname" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbDepartment" Name="dept" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbRequestType" Name="rt" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbStatus" Name="status" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbWorkflow" Name="work" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbCompany" Name="comp" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtRemarks" Name="remarks" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbMasterData" Name="rm" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDate" Name="date" PropertyName="Date" DbType="DateTime" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbPriority" Name="prio" PropertyName="Value" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtResponse" Name="response" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="''" Name="module" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDocNum" DefaultValue="" Name="dn" PropertyName="Text" />
                 </InsertParameters>
             </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the `SqlDataSource` and `ASPxTextBox` markup to let us find out possible cause of this issue. Try using `txtLName_Init()` event handler to see the unique ID, e.g. `var textbox = sender as ASPxTextBox; Debug.WriteLine(textbox.UniqueID);`.

Comment: I have already the problem but whenever I enter the value for date it would always display error.

Comment: Is that `txtLname` contained inside `GridView`'s `ItemTemplate` or other container? If the textbox doesn't contained inside any container you can use the control name directly, but if using any container then you should use container name too, e.g. `GridView1$txtLname`.

Comment: I recently just solved this, I have just put it inside the formlayout fields. sigh.